# Can not create Alarm Manager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

Sorry for my bad English. I faced with the problem. I try to create persistent alarm notification. Alarm notification must start every 10 seconds. I am using Alarm Manager,but it doest't work. What i am doing wrong?

```
public class RemindReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Class<?> activityClass;

public RemindReceiver() {

}

public RemindReceiver(Class<?> activityClass) {

    this.activityClass = activityClass;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Some Text", System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent intentTL = new Intent(context, activityClass);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Title", "Some Text",
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentTL, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notifyManager.notify(1, notification);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5, pendingIntent);
}

public void setRemind(Context context) {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RemindReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5 , pendingIntent);
}}
```

Fragment:

```
public class PersonListFragment extends Fragment {

private RemindReceiver remindReceiver;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_list_fragment_layout, container, false);

    Button nextButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    ListView personListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name_list_view);
    List<Person> personList = PersonListGenerator.generate();

    PersonListAdapter adapter = new PersonListAdapter(getActivity(), personList);
    personListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    remindReceiver = new RemindReceiver(PersonListActivity.class);
    remindReceiver.setRemind(context);
    remindReceiver.onReceive(getActivity(), new Intent());

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExpandablePersonListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}}
```

And piece of my Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<receiver android:name=".utility.RemindReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? Do you get an error? Does anything at all happen?

Comment: Nothing happend, but i am waiting notification.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() ?

e.g.:

```
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000 * 5, pendingIntent);
```

I vaguely remember AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP needing SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() and not System.currentTimeMillis()

I can't however find where I read this before. I will update when I find it.

edit:

According to: [AlarmManager.set(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation) sdk docs..](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> Parameters
>
> - type:  One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, or RTC_WAKEUP. triggerAtMillis   time in milliseconds that the alarm should
>     go off, using the
> - appropriate: clock (depending on the alarm type).
> - operation: Action to perform when the alarm goes off; typically comes from IntentSender.getBroadcast().

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to wake up every **10 seconds**, consider the note at [`setRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> Note: for timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and
>   much more efficient to use `Handler`.

Apart from that, if you just test with 10 seconds, it is **inaccurate by design** as of API 19:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

Thus, the alarm will not be delivered within the 10 seconds, because it will be delayed.

For me, that meant sometimes waiting a minute or more for my alarm, which worked pre-API-19.

Thus, you can expect exact alarm wakeup behavior only if you do not use `setRepeating`.

(Apart from that, @Damian has the right direction with his answer that the times need to be matched): use either

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000 * 5, 
    1000 * 5, 
    pendingIntent);
```

or try the current system time:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 5, 
    1000 * 5, 
    pendingIntent);
```

Please change your code to include the `+1000 * 5`. Else the alarm is scheduled at the moment of execution, and thus, passes.