# AlarmManager is not repeating

Tags: android, repeatingalarm

I can't make AlarmManager repeating. I have tried a lot of examples, but for me they don't work. Alarm always fires only once, then nothing happens.
I ran all examples on my device (android 4.4.2) and all the examples  work completely the same. Just one fire, and then nothing.
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the code of the last example:
Receiver:

```
package net.desme.alarmtest;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // For example
        wl.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 6, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.desme.alarmtest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AlarmManagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".Alarm" android:process=":remote" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity:

```
package net.desme.alarmtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity {
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_manager);

        findViewById(R.id.start_repeating).setOnClickListener(mStartRepeatingListener);
        findViewById(R.id.stop_repeating).setOnClickListener(mStopRepeatingListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mStartRepeatingListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alarm.setAlarm(getApplicationContext());
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener mStopRepeatingListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alarm.cancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
        }
    };
}
```

Also i tried these:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/31/how-to-setup-a-repeating-alarm-in-android/

and much more but i cant post it because the red tip says that i need at least 10 reputation

### EDIT

The problem was that in API 19+ all alarms are inexact. Here is what the documentation says:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
> application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
> exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
> applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
> continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
> treated as exact.

And possible solutions:

> Note: for timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) > it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler
>
> If your application wants to allow the delivery times to drift in order to guarantee that at least a certain time interval always elapses between alarms, then the approach to take is to use one-time alarms, scheduling the next one yourself when handling each alarm delivery.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32274099/1587329

Comment: Which API level are you using, 22?

Comment: @user------- omg, why i didn't see that note in documentation? :D it actually explains everything. I just was so stupid that i didnt read  it. thank for help

Comment: You are welcome. Would you like a similar answer here, for completeness, or is this enough for you?

Answer (score -1):

this is the solution for starting an alarm for repeating with 10 seconds interval, but it's pending intent is different, because i used this method to start service after 10 seconds interval, therefore use it according to your requirement,

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Service_class.class);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            36000 * 1000, pintent);
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine in Android 4.4.2 API 22. Maybe the `AlarmManager` on your device/API is acting differently; perhaps overriding the frequency since it's so short. Do you really need 6 seconds interval? Try increasing the frequency over a minute, i.e. > 60000.

Comment: i set the frequency to 3 minutes (`AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES / 5`), and still nothing. but actually i read the documentation for `[setRepeating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating) and now i understand what is my problem.